# Two almost identical bits of javascript on one page, only one works

Tags: javascript

I have to generate two random numbers on my page. I'm using this javascript:

```
<script>
 window.onload = generateRandomNumber1;
 function generateRandomNumber1(){
     var n = 30;
     var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     document.getElementById("random1").innerHTML = number;
    }

 window.onload = generateRandomNumber2;
 function generateRandomNumber2(){
     var n = 30;
     var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     document.getElementById("random2").innerHTML = number;
    }
</script>
```

Only the second chunk of code, generateRandomNumber2, works. Both work individually, but only one works when they are together.

I'm sure there is probably some really basic solution, but I'm a real novice on javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console? What's your (relevant) HTML?

Comment: you are overriding the onload function. Only one onload listener can be there when assigning this way. Go through this [link](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/) to have more information about how to use window.onload. when onload event will fire it will call window.onload(), hence the function last assigned will get a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `window.onload` so only the second one will have any effect.  Instead, create a new function that calls both:

```
window.onload = function() {
    generateRandomNumber1();
    generateRandomNumber2();
};
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I get it. I hadn't even noticed that I was doing window.onload in the same bit of script. I'll try this, but I may need to ask another question about how to implement it. I'll give it a go myself though, and let you know how I get on. PS Sorry for my tardy response, thought I was being notified when people replied, but I must have set something up wrong. Thought everyone was ignoring me. Should have known better from the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Wow, that actually worked really well. Not surprised that it worked, just surprised that I was able to implement it.

Comment: I have one more question about how fast this java runs. But rather than hijack my own thread, which is probably bad form, I'll start a new one. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is overwritting the window.onload event. Instead you should try creating a wrapper anonymous function to call both functions:

```
window.onload = function(){
  generateRandomNumber1();
  generateRandomNumber2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the first `window.onload` with the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning window.onload. Have window.onload call another function that calls both of your random number functions.